# About an specific user not writing properly

Tags: discussion, specific-user

I have observed that there is a user out there that I think is not being nice/polite/etc when he leaves comments on post.

I checked the activity and are some of them

> is this question a joke?  $S_i=\frac {1}{i^2}...$
>
> what the heck is $f$?
>
> Why is it not obvious that (1) converges if $∈^1()$. Doesn't it obviously converge...? As a reminder, $∈^1()$ implies $∫_|()|<∞$, so obviously $∫_|(ℎ)|ℎ<∞$...
>
> is what correct? do u want to end up with the uniform distribution? can you be more precise
>
> any non-measurable set.........? am i missing something
>
> you should say what $_=_+(_)$ means.....
>
> you should say what $=ℎ+()$ means....
>
> why $=0$????????

And I did flag one of his comments and my flag was rejected.

This user also comments a lot of good hints/help/etc but even still I don't think that is a justification for letting him to write like that.

What should be done about it?

Comment: Personally (from what you quoted) I don't mind their comment rude at all. Anyway, just flag those comments that you found rude.

Comment: I can't believe it

Comment: @ArcticChar  I agree.  There's nothing rude in these comments.  The OP seems to be reading tone into the comments which may not be there.  They are mostly asking for clarification.

Comment: FWIW I feel the comments shown in the question are unnecessarily brusque and the tone demanding. But I don't think I would flag them as "rude/abusive", I would prefer to work around the user as far as possible. As others have pointed out, I too could be reading tone into the comments which may not be there, so I would prefer to avoid risking a confrontation when I may not be objective about this.

Comment: @Brahadeesh "I would prefer to work around the user as far as possible." well that would be perfect, but how to do that? when he is free to comment everywhere (including therefore your _own_ post).

Comment: @Isa If it does not bother you to see such comments under your questions/answers, then just ignore them. One is under no compulsion to reply to every comment, after all. If it does bother you to see such comments under your questions/answers, then perhaps you can mention it once to that user that you do not wish to be contacted by them in the comments. If they persist in engaging you in comments, you could then flag your post for moderator attention and leave it to them to handle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These comments paint me a picture of a demanding, impatient user, who tries to make askers to feel a little bad for wasting their time. I agree that this is not behaviour that we want on MSE ... if this is indeed the case! There are some things to bear in mind:

- These are cherry-picked examples, removed from context, to illustrate a trend. When lined up like this, away from their respective questions/replies/follow-up comments/etc, they will likely appear more damning than they actually are. Also bear in mind that most askers will only see one or two of these comments, so in order for a comment to be genuinely problematic, it needs to be problematic in isolation.
- The grammar of the comments suggests to me that their author is not a native English speaker. Conveying a tone takes some skill in a language, and avoiding conveying a specific tone is even more tricky (and sometimes challenging even for native speakers). A lot of the issues in these comments could be explained by a simple language barrier.
- While I would definitely have phrased at least half of these comments differently had I written them, we do need to give users leeway to express themselves. Some of the comments walk close to the line of unacceptable rudeness, but I personally wouldn't censure them for anything they've written here.
- The last comment possibly has multiple question marks simply to bring the comment up to the minimum $15$ characters.

I do appreciate what you're trying to achieve here. I see my fair share of curt comments directed at askers, particularly new and naive askers. If I find a comment that I think is brusque, demanding, impatient, etc, but not enough to be actionable, I usually leave another comment, saying more or less the same thing, but with a more gentle, inviting tone. Or, I will leave simple questions to get the asker to engage with me in the comments. Flagging and deleting rude comments is not the only way to help askers have a positive interaction with the site.

Comment: Concerning  your last bullet point, it could be applicable to the quoted first comment too, since "What is $f$?" again does not meet the characters requirement.

Comment: What an answer Theo Bendit, thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

For a native English-speaker the comments you've chosen to highlight are mostly fine. Two of the comments might be regarded as brusque but not rude.  There are two sides to this I suppose:

**Thesis**

When writing comments or answers it's worth being aware that it's easy for others to miss nuance.  In particular, the things that we can express through tone of voice, or a smile/frown, all vanish, and readers can have a hard time telling when something is intended as humorous, sarcastic, or is even just expressing your own frustation.

**Antithesis**

As readers, we have to remember that we might be putting our own moods and feelings onto the writer.  If I'm in a bad mood already because of something a colleague has said to me, I am much more likely to read hostile intent into a comment or answer on the page because I'm primed to be defensive.  If you go looking through someone's comments posts looking for "rude" comments, you're much more likely to find things you categorise as rude.

**Synthesis**

It's best to give the benefit of the doubt unless there is a very strong indication that there is something rude about a comment -- and that pretty much means name-calling, swear-words, or other ad hominem attacks.  You can flag comments you think are abusive, as *Arctic Char* called out -- but if your flag is rejected then you need to consider that you might have been too sensitive, or that the general level of conversation is not what you were expecting (to be cliched about it: if you're sat in a cheap bar in a bad neighbourhood you shouldn't be expecting church-language from the people around you).

Comment: 'You haven't given us any easy way to look at other comments this user might have written, so we have no basis for comparison.' I thought was not correct to expose users

Comment: @Isa I did say "easy" way -- there's enough there to identify the user with a quick search so you've exposed them already.  Since you've done that it seems as though you've picked comments to support your question (which may not be true but it's the appearance of it).  Ideally you would have removed the question titles from your images as searching comment text is much harder

Comment: Then why did you say: _so we have no basis for comparison._

Comment: @Isa forgive me, I'll edit that out.  I was trying not to encourage people to go searching for that user; I see that was actually your intent all along.

Comment: Nevermind:) .Not really I was about to write his 'name' after reading the text your just removed.

Comment: The thing is that I have been here in this site for a while and this is the first time that I find such consecutive inappropriate comments by an specific user. So I don't think this is on me.

Comment: @Isa What was inappropriate about the comments? Most of them seem just fine(Is it the ellipsis... excess question marks????). It seems like most people so far don't find the comments as rude as you have

Comment: @PaulPlummer each of his comments have 'something' annoying/inappropriate. In that comment yes, why to put lots of marks. Can you see the problem??????? yes?

Comment: @PaulPlummer In the first comment, he uses the word _heck_ and google translate states _expressing surprise, frustration, or dismay._ I think it should not be used specially when dealing with someone that it's trying to learn. In the 2nd comment he uses the three dots (didn't know they had name 'ellipsis' :) plus the word _obviously_. Notice how he is combining them, looks gloomy and feels negative to the reader. The same happens with comment 5th,6th and 7th. The 3rd comment can pass.. And in the 4th comment he ask if the question is a joke. [*]

Comment: [*] Why in the world someone would do that? OP came here for help or hints  and perhaps their question was really stupid (honestly) but it's not something that you should tell one way or another.

Comment: Am I missing something is not a joke. it's a statement of not understanding how an OP got to that conclusion.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee In an earlier version of the question, the fourth comment was something like "is this a joke?" You can take a look at the edit history of the question; that comment had been subsequently deleted and so it was removed from the list.

Comment: Whole site is a waste of space anyways. it doesn't bother me.

Comment: @Brahadeesh Actually I just realized that I forgot to write that comment :/ But I won't edit since that would put the question on main again..

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee the comment that I forgot was this:$\quad$ is this question a joke? $S_i=\frac{1}{i^2}$...

Comment: whole site is a joke to the elites in math.

Comment: Concerning the comments with lots of question marks, a possible reason is that they have to satisfy the minimum character requirement.

Answer (score -2):

Mostly hints and clarification about where you're stuck.  To not waste time, people need three things, the set of things you know about the problem, the set of reasons you're stuck, and set of information needed to answer the question.  If they have the latter, they need to know the previous two, to find a way to tell you what you don't have. In modular arithmetic, that could mean relying on linear polynomials, or long division for example. They want to tell you what you don't already have, that might mean introducing definitions, or unknown rules used thoroughly in the topic.

Comment: yes but there are many ways to ask for those 3 things. One could be brusque or rude _or_ kind or polite, etc. brusque is definitely not friendly and SE encourage to avoid it.

Comment: Sure, but the point is precise language, and definitions are used in mathematics. I actually had to look up what brusque meant.

Comment: Yes. So do you think the definition of 'brusque' fits?

Comment: No, but I'm an Asperger's case apparently.

Comment: ah. well. Don't say that :)